# Simplifying overly complicated meshes created by arrays and curves?

Tags: vertices, geometry

I've been using arrays and curves to create vines and strands of hair on models

It gives me a lot of control, but when I convert them to a mesh to edit them for 3D printing, but the meshes are crazy complicated and the make blender unstable.

Is there a way to reduce the amount of geometry in a controlled way so that I still have smooth surfaces. The below image is one of the simpler ones. Some of them get insane. Particularly when I use a subdivision surface modifier.

I'm looking for a better way to do things, but until I find one I'm sticking with this.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you use mesh arrayed along a curve, make sure that the object is not too high in polygons, so for example don't apply any *Subdivision Surface* modifier (or keep it low). If you've already applied the *Subdivision Surface* modifier, you can use tools to simplify your mesh, maybe the safest is <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve* and play with the *Angle* value in the *Operator* box (bottom left of your 3D view). You can also try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Un-Subdivide*.

You can also play with the curve's *Resolution* value (*Properties panel > Object Data > Shape > Resolution Preview*), the number will determine the amount of segments between 2 vertices of your curve, and therefore the number of vertices you'll have once converted to mesh.

If you use a curve profile rather than a mesh object, don't forget to set the resolution for the profile as well.